# Jonah at the bottom of mountains, Jonah 2:6

Tags: kjv

What was Jonah mean that he went down to the "bottom of the mountains" and the "earth with her bars was about me forever"?

Comment: Welcome to BHSX.  Thanks for your question.  I have slightly edited the question to help this site because it requires a specific Bible passage to analyse.  See the Tour below for more details.

Answer (score 1):

There are two metaphors in Jonah 2:6 - the "bottoms of the mountains" and "bars of earth around me".

Ellicott correctly comments here:

> **Bottoms of the mountains**.--Literally, ends or cuttings off, as, in
>   margin. So the Vulg. extrema montium. Mountains were in the Hebrew
>   conception the pillars of the world (see Job 9:6; Job 26:11), having
>   their foundations firmly planted in the sea. These "hidden bases of
>   the hills" were therefore the verge of the earth itself, and one lost
>   among them would be close on the under-world of death.

On "The Bars of death" Ellicott further comments:

> **The earth with her bars** . . .--Literally, the earth her bars behind me for ever; i.e., the earth's gates were closed upon me for
>   ever, there was no possibility of return. The metaphor of a gateway to
>   sheol is common (Isaiah 38:10, &c.), but the earth is nowhere else
>   said to be so guarded. Ewald therefore proposes to read sheol here.
>   But it is quite as natural to imagine a guarded passage out of the
>   land of the living as into the land of the dead.

Thus, Jonah was fearful that, before he prayed (Jonah 2:1) he was as good as dead and would never return to normal life.  It was as though he had been thrown in "sheol" (the place of the dead) and the bars of the gate had been closed behind him.  But God rescued him when he prayed.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your great answer Mac's Musing

Any way in view of my own perception, i assume verse 6 to take it literally hence Jonah said **I went down** not **swim down** and it comes up to my assumption that this is to be taken literally in a reason before Jonah was swallowed by the great fish, behind his story in account of 2King 14:25 that jonah was residing in a mountainous region of Gathhepher when God commanded him to go to Nineveh.

Jonah 2:6 **I went down to the bottoms of the mountains**; **the earth with her bars was about me for ever**: yet hast thou **brought up my life from corruption**, O LORD my God.

I may conclude that this is a powerful part of Jonah’s prophetic testimony in his prayer accepting that he is running away from God’s hiding himself down to the bottom of the mountains `*he came down from mountainous region of Gathhepher and aboard to a ship heading to Tarshish considering this as a bottom of the mountain*` to stay away or hide from God’s command where he was consumed by his own desire and have corrupted his life. And yet because of his heartfelt affliction prayer in verse 2 God heard him and delivered him from the imprisonment of his innermost pride while he is still in the belly.

In addition in Jonah 2:7 **When my soul fainted within me I remembered the LORD**: and my **prayer came in unto thee, into thine holy temple**. 
At the time when Jonah is very weak and fainted in a dark belly of sheol he remember and realized the **Word of the God** is talking to him and he begun talking/praying to God in spirit and in truth for he acknowledge on that very moment that he was as a temple of the Holy Spirit as God is talking to him in spirit, and Jonah was awaken from his lying vanity and agreed a vow on God’s command. Jonah's encounter with God change him where he stand on his testimony as prophetic word on the next verse that those who don't repent will be destroyed.

I hope you got what i mean and hope i am not mistaken for my perception

Bless God and God will Bless in return.

Comment: I think I understand your interpretation.  I think it a little strained in view of the previous several verses which describe Jonah underwater, below the waves, wrapped in seaweed.  Further, no where else do we find the bottom of a mountain (ie the valley floor) ever described as "roots of mountains".  That is, the bottom of a mountain is quite different from the roots of the mountains below sea level.

Comment: so also with me i feel strained of my perception, hope some others could make a comment of what there thoughts about this.

Answer (score 0):

The bottoms of the mountains are indeed meant to be acknowledged as below sea level.. hypothetically if you could lower the existing sea level, what would be exposed to our eye would be what would appear to look exactly like mountains (i.e. Appalachian Mts.)for example.  Being from the Appalachian mountains, I'm totally convinced that these old mountains were undoubtedly carved out by the flood.  There is just no two ways about it. Thanks for allowing me to comment. Bless the Lord. His mercy endures forever.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).